# When running a sh file in linux, why do I have to run ./name.sh?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file called x.sh that I want to execute. If I run:

```
x.sh
```

then I get:

```
x.sh: command not found
```

If I run:

```
./x.sh
```

then it runs correctly. Why do I have to type in ./ first?

Comment: the `.` means "this directory" and since it's not in the PATH variable you need the full path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the current directory is not into the `PATH` environment variable by default, and executables without a path qualification are searched only inside the directory specified by `PATH`. You can change this behavior by adding `.` to the end of `PATH`, but it's not common practice, you'll just get used to this UNIXism.

The idea behind this is that, if executables were searched first inside the current directory, a malicious user could put inside his home directory an executable named e.g. `ls` or `grep` or some other commonly used command, tricking the administrator to use it, maybe with superuser powers. On the other hand, this problem is not much felt if you put `.` at the end of `PATH`, since in that case the system directories are searched first.

*But*: our malicious user could still create his dangerous scripts named as common typos of often used commands, e.g. `sl` for `ls` (protip: bind it to [Steam Locomotive](http://debaday.livejournal.com/22802.html) and you won't be tricked anyway `:D`).

So you see that it's still better to be safe that, if you type an executable name without a path qualification, you are sure you're running something from system directories (and thus supposedly safe).

Comment: Do you know why it is not searched? Why would I not want to make it be searched by default (assumming that's possible)?

Comment: @dan: Because otherwise, it would make it too easy to accidentally run the wrong thing (imagine you'd create a script called `ls`).

Answer (score 5):

Because the current directory is normally not included in the default PATH, for security reasons: by NOT looking in the current directory all kinds of nastiness that could be caused by planting a malicious program with the name of a legitimate utility can be avoided.  As an example, imagine someone manages to plant a script called `ls` in your directory, and that script executes `rm *`.

If you wish to include the current directory in your path, and you're using bash as your default shell, you can add the path via your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Based on the explanation above, the risk posed by rogue programs is reduced by looking in `.` last, so all well known legitimate programs will be found before . is checked.

You **could** also modify the systemwide settings via `/etc/profile` but that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: How do I find out the current path?

Comment: `echo $PATH` in your shell (meaning print out the environment variable called PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Because current directory is not in PATH (unlike cmd in Windows). It is a security feature so that malicious scripts in your current directory are not accidentally run.

Though it is not advisable, to satisfy curiosity, you can add `.` to the PATH and then you will see that `x.sh` will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly specify a directory then the shell searches through the directories listed in your `$PATH` for the named executable. If your `$PATH` does not include `.` then the current directory is not searched.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

This is on purpose. If the current directory were searched then the command you type could potentially change based on what directory you're in. This would allow a malicious user to place a binary named `ls` or `cp` into directories you frequent and trick you into running a different program.

```
$ cat /tmp/ls
rm -rf ~/*
$ cd /tmp
$ ls
*kaboom*
```

I strongly recommend you *not* add `.` to your `$PATH`. You will quickly get used to typing `./`, it's no big deal.

Comment: Also: Even if you put `.` after the default search path, you'd still be vulnerable to typos (e.g, `la`, `cdd`, `bim`...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute your file by typing simply 
`x.sh`
because the present working directory isn't in your $PATH. To see your present working directory, type

```
$ pwd
```

To see your $PATH, type

```
$ echo $PATH
```

To add the current directory to your $PATH for this session, type

```
$ PATH=$PATH:.
```

To add it permanently, edit the file `.profile` in your home directory.

Comment: Adding `.` to `PATH` is a bad idea security-wise. Don't do it.